# Прошел дождь и дети пошли гулять - об этом было сказано позже. Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: бессоюзное

Общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями сложносочиненного предложения третья часть, предшествующая им и связанная с ними бессоюзной связью: Берегов не видать: их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны разлива (М. Г.);

Но: Через час явилась возможность ехать: метель утихла, небо прояснилось, и мы отправились (П.) — последняя часть не входит в разъяснение.

Если же дано бессоюзное предложение, в котором часть после тире поясняет обе части слева от тире:

Прошел дождь и дети пошли гулять - об этом было сказано позже

Можно ли не ставить запятую перед И, чтобы показать, что часть после тире относится к всему сложносочиненному предложению слева от тире?

Или запятая обязательна:

Прошел дождь, и дети пошли гулять - об этом было сказано позже.

Если запятая не нужна, то каким правилом это можно объяснить?

Comment: "Было сказано" — стилистически плохо. Варианты: было рассказано, написано, сообщено.

Answer (score 3):

**Прошел дождь  и дети пошли гулять — об этом было сказано позже.**

Предложение, вероятно, придуманное, поэтому лучше сказать так: **Прошел дождь и дети пошли гулять — об этом мы узнали позже.**

Общей является бессоюзная связь, запятая не ставится.

**Пояснение**

Общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями сложносочиненного предложения третья часть, предшествующая им и связанная с ними бессоюзной связью: **Берегов не видать: их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны разлива** (М. Г.);
Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Но это предложение можно записать **и с тире** (знак не так важен): **Берегов не видать — их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны разлива.**

А перед местоимением ***это*** ставится именно тире: Идёт большая вода — это всего интереснее (Горб.);